# How to write a function that will output two values in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-value

Suppose researchers have analyzed data from the spread of a particular disease and have fit the data to the following model, which predicts the number of people in a small population who will have the disease on day t:

```
()=20^3-t^4/100
```

Define a function named max_infection that will compute 
`()` for 20 days (i.e. for `1≤≤20`) and return two values:

- the day at which the most people are infected, and
- the number of people infected on that day.

I need to write a function that will return two values but I am not sure how to do that. I am new to python and am completely confused. I know I need to define the function first but even that in itself is still confusing to me

There are no arguments passed to this function. The expected answer is `16.875` people infected on day `15`.

Comment: You can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) about _tuples_. You can't return two values, but returning a tuple with two elements is just as good.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps you understand what you want to achieve:

```
def fun_a():
    a = 23
    b = 24
    return a ,b


c ,d = fun_a()
print(c, d)
```

OUTPUT:

`23 24`

Also another way to achieve this can be using a `list` or `tuple` to return the data.

Here is how you return a tuple:

```
class Test: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.str = "stackoverflow"
        self.x = 20   

# This function returns an object of Test 
def fun(): 
    return Test() 

# Driver code to test above method 
t = fun()  
print(t.str) 
print(t.x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
stackoverflow
20
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: May I kindly suggest that you revise your terminology ?

Comment: Sure @brunodesthuilliers. Instead I'd ask you to kindly edit the post in order to make it more readable and standardized. Can't thank you enough